# placing router links in a sliding sidebar

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have created a single page app using react-router, but I am wanting to now place my router links in a sidebar which transitions in from the left.

I have been trying for a few days now but no matter what I seem to do my route links keep just appearing either on their own and not in the sidebar component or they want to render in the sidebar component once they are clicked on.

Sidebar component:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import './SideDrawer.css';
import {BrowserRouter, Route, Link} from 'react-router-dom';

const routes = [
  {
  path: '/',
  exact: true,
  sidebar: () => <div></div>,
  main: () => <p>Home</p>
  },
  {
  path: '/dogs',
  sidebar: () => <div>Dogs</div>,
  main: () => <p>Dogs</p>
  }
];


const sideDrawer = props => {
  let drawerClasses = 'side-drawer'

  if (props.show) {
    drawerClasses='side-drawer open'
  }
  return(
    <div className='Main'>
    <nav className={drawerClasses}>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <div style={{display: 'flex'}}>
        <div className='navBar'>
          <ul style={{listStyleType: 'none'}}>
            <li><Link to='/'>Home</Link></li>
            <li><Link to='/dogs'>Dogs</Link></li>
          </ul>


        </div>

          <div style={{flex:1, padding:'0px'}}>
            {routes.map((route) => (
              <Route
                key={route.path}
                path={route.path}
                exact={route.exact}
                component={route.main}
                />
            ))}
          </div>
      </div>
    </BrowserRouter>

 </nav>

</div>
);
};


export default sideDrawer;
```

App Component:

```
class App extends Component {
  state ={
    sideDrawerOpen: false
  };
  drawerToggleClickHandler = () => {
    this.setState((prevState) => {
      return {sideDrawerOpen: !prevState.sideDrawerOpen};
    });
  };

  backdropClickHandler = () => {
    this.setState({sideDrawerOpen: false});
  };

  render() {
    let backDrop;

    if (this.state.sideDrawerOpen) {
      backDrop = <Backdrop click={this.backdropClickHandler}/>;
    }
    return (
      <div style={{height:'100%'}} className="App">
        <Toolbar drawerClickHandler ={this.drawerToggleClickHandler}/>
        <SideDrawer show={this.state.sideDrawerOpen}/>
        {backDrop}
        <main style={{marginTop:'64px'}}>
        'place lists here'
        </main>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App
```

I was hoping for the sliding sidebar to render the router-links, and once clicked they will render the links contents in the space beside/behind the sliding sidebar. But instead it is wanting to render the links inside the sidebar also.

Comment: In such a case you need to define the Routes within the BackDrop component and also BrowserRouter must wrap both BackDrop and SideDrawer

Comment: I've made something similar to this : App.jsx file in that I'm rendering Main and Sidenav file, Sidenav file is having all the `<Link>` and Main file is having all the `<Route>`
 .https://reactize.herokuapp.com, Check the code from this repository : https://github.com/GermaVinsmoke/Reactize

Comment: All I’m wanting is to click on the link in the sliding sidebar and it render the link route in the main component. I’m leaning towards I might be better off using <a href''> tags and not use react router. But I’m not sure I’m really quite new to it all. Just teaching myself a couple hours a night when I have time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find a solution for my issue.

I created a sidebar.js component and placed the links inside of it.
I then created a Hamburger styled button icon, and used this.state and a buttonToggle() method to to change the state and display the  component which contains the links I wanted in the sidebar while still rendering them in the main component. 
It may not be the best way, but it is the best way I could find for now on my own. I have struggled to find much help for this issue.

My code:

SideBar.js

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import './App.css';
import {BrowserRouter, Route, Link} from 'react-router-dom';

class SideBar extends Component {
  render(){
    return(
      <div style={{display: 'flex'}}>
        <div className='navBar'>
          <ul style={{listStyleType: 'none'}}>
            <li><Link to='/'>Home</Link></li>
            <li><Link to='/dogs'>MyDogs</Link></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        </div>
    );
  }
}


export default SideBar;
```

DrawerToggleButton.js

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import './drawerToggleButton.css';
import SideBar from './sidebar.js';

const DrawerToggleButton = props => (
  <button className='toggle-button' onClick={props.click}>
    <div className='toggle-button-line'></div>
    <div className='toggle-button-line'></div>
    <div className='toggle-button-line'></div>
  </button>
);

class DrawerToggleButtonBind extends Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      message: false
     }
  }

  buttonToggle(){
    this.setState({
      message: !this.state.message
    })
  }

  render(){
    return(
      <div className="DrawerToggleBind">
        <button className='toggle-button' onClick = { () => this.buttonToggle()} >
          <div className='toggle-button-line'></div>
          <div className='toggle-button-line'></div>
          <div className='toggle-button-line'></div>
        </button>
        {this.state.message ? <div><SideBar/></div>: null}
      </div>
   )
  }
}

export default DrawerToggleButtonBind;
```

App.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {BrowserRouter, Route, Link} from 'react-router-dom';
import './App.css';
import Home from './home.js';
import DogsList from './dogslist.js';
import DrawerToggleButtonBind from './drawerToggleButton.js';


const routes = [
  {
  path: '/',
  exact: true,
  sidebar: () => <div>Home</div>,
  main: () => <Home/>
  },
  {
  path: '/dogs',
  sidebar: () => <div>Dogs</div>,
  main: () => <DogsList/>
  }
];



  class App extends Component {

  render() {
    return(
      <div>
       <BrowserRouter>
        <DrawerToggleButtonBind/>
          <div style={{flex:1, padding:'0px'}}>
            {routes.map((route) => (
             <Route
              key={route.path}
              path={route.path}
              exact={route.exact}
              component={route.main}
              />
          ))}
        </div>
       </BrowserRouter>
      </div>
   )
  }
}

export default App;
```